# How do you pass a variable from 'context' to a page query? | Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

Attempting to pass a 'context' variable to a page query I get an error telling me the variable isn't provided.

From my `gatsby-node.js` file:

```
createPage({
  path: `/portfolio/${pg.order}`,
  component: require.resolve("./src/pages/portfolio.js"),
  context: { pgNum: pg.order },
})
```

My page query:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($pgNum: Int!) {
    strapiPortfolioPages(order: { eq: $pgNum }) {
      layer
      widths
      ...
    }
  }
```

Gatsby tells me: "Variable "$pgNum" of required type "Int!" was not provided."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Variable "$pgNum" of required type "Int!" was not provided."

This means that your `$pgNum` variable is non-nullable because of the `Int!` since the exclamation mark (`!`) stands for a non-nullable (required) value in GraphQL(for further information check the [Schema and Types GraphQL documentation](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/)). In other words, your query is passing a `null` value to a non-nullable variable so you have a `null` value somewhere.

An easy way to bypass it (after checking your values) is removing the nullability of the query by:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($pgNum: Int) {
    strapiPortfolioPages(order: { eq: $pgNum }) {
      layer
      widths
      ...
    }
  }
```